# how to create session in php with mongodb

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

in node.js i will create mongodb session like this.

```
 app.configure(function()

{

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'MY SECRET',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: 'MY SESSION DB',
        host: 'localhost',
        port:88888
    })
}));
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(app.router);
```

});

how to create session with mongodb in php.i am new one for php..i want to create session with mongodb in php(webserver: apache),so let me know how to create

Answer (score 4):

You must use a session handler to accomplish this. Normally we don't answer these sort of questions which lack research of any kind but, this one time, here is a small, extremely simple, self contained edition I have:

```
class Session{

    public $db;

    /**
     * This decides the lifetime (in seconds) of the session
     *
     * @access private
     * @var int
     */
    public $life_time='+2 weeks';


    /**
     * This stores the found session collection so that we don't
     * waste resources by constantly going back for it
     *
     * @access private
     * @var sessions
     */
    private $_session = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function open() {

        // Ensure index on Session ID
        $this->db->sessions->ensureIndex(array('session_id' => 1), array("unique" => true));

        // Register this object as the session handler
        session_set_save_handler(
            array( $this, "openSession" ),
            array( $this, "closeSession" ),
            array( $this, "readSession" ),
            array( $this, "writeSession"),
            array( $this, "destroySession"),
            array( $this, "gcSession" )
        );
        session_start(); // Start the damn session
    }

    /**
     * Open session
     *
     * This function opens a session from a save path.
     * The save path can be changed the method of opening also can
     * but we do not change that we just do the basics and return
     *
     * @param string $save_path
     * @param string $session_name
     */
    function openSession( $save_path, $session_name ) {

        global $sess_save_path;

        $sess_save_path = $save_path;

        // Don't need to do anything. Just return TRUE.
        return true;

    }

    /**
     * This function closes the session (end of session)
     */
    function closeSession() {

        // Return true to indicate session closed
        return true;

    }

    /**
     * This is the read function that is called when we open a session.
     * This function attempts to find a session from the Db. If it cannot then
     * the session class variable will remain null.
     *
     * @param string $id
     */
    function readSession( $id ) {

        // Set empty result
        $data = '';

        // Fetch session data from the selected database
        $time = time();

        $this->_sessions = $this->db->sessions->findOne(array("session_id"=>$id));

        if (!empty($this->_sessions)) {
            $data = $this->_sessions['session_data'];
        }

        return $data;

    }

    /**
     * This is the write function. It is called when the session closes and
     * writes all new data to the Db. It will do two actions depending on whether or not
     * a session already exists. If the session does exist it will just update the session
     * otherwise it will insert a new session.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param mixed $data
     *
     * @todo Need to make this function aware of other users since php sessions are not always unique maybe delete all old sessions.
     */
    function writeSession( $id, $data ) {

        //Write details to session table
        $time = strtotime('+2 weeks');

        // If the user is logged in record their uid
        $uid = $_SESSION['logged'] ? $_SESSION['uid'] : 0;

        $fields = array(
            "session_id"=>$id,
            "user_id"=>$uid,
            "session_data"=>$data,
            "expires"=>$time,
            "active"=>1
        );

        $fg = $this->db->sessions->update(array("session_id"=>$id), array('$set'=>$fields), array("upsert"=>true));

        // DONE
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when a user calls session_destroy(). It
     * kills the session and removes it.
     *
     * @param string $id
     */
    function destroySession( $id ) {

        // Remove from Db
        $this->db->sessions->remove(array("session_id" => $id), true);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This function GCs (Garbage Collection) all old and out of date sessions
     * which still exist in the Db. It will remove by comparing the current to the time of
     * expiring on the session record.
     *
     * @todo Make a cronjob to delete all sessions after about a day old and are still inactive
     */
    function gcSession() {
        $this->db->sessions->remove(array('expires' => array('$lt' => strtotime($this->life_time))));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
$session = new Session;
$session->db=$mongo->my_db;
$session->open();
```

It is a very basic example of how to do this.

Afterwards you can just use it like a normal session like so:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
```